# __new__ of Metaclass throw errors

Tags: python

I'm testing use of metaclass and stuck on creating the object. The new method throws error "missing 3 required positional arguments":

```
bash-4.4$ python3 sftester.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sftester.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sorrogatefactory import make_SA_Sorrogate
  File "/home/alelai/anvil9/kafka-client-new/sorrogatefactory.py", line 42, in <module>
    class make_SA_Sorrogate(SA_AddOn, metaclass=SorrogateFactory()):
TypeError: __new__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'classname', 'supers', and 'classdict'



bash-4.4$ cat sftester.py
from sorrogatefactory2 import SorrogateFactory, make_SA_Sorrogate

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sa_sorrogate = make_SA_Sorrogate()



bash-4.4$ cat sorrogatefactory2.py
class SorrogateFactory(object):

    def __call__(self, classname, supers, classdict):
            print("In __call__")
            print("Making " + classname + " of" + " classname")
            Class = self.__new__(classname, supers, classdict)
            self.__init__(Class, classname, supers, classdict)
            return Class

    def __new__(self, classname, supers, classdict):
            print("In __new__")
            return type(classname, supers, classdict)

    def __init__(self):
            print("In __init__")
            pass


class SA_AddOn(object):
    pass

class make_SA_Sorrogate(SA_AddOn, metaclass=SorrogateFactory()):

    def dumb(slef):
            pass
```

It look like the _*new*_() method mentioned in the error message is not the _*new*_() method of SorrogateFactory. What is the catch here?

Comment: What is `make_SA_Sorrogate`? You appear to be confusing the metaclass's `__new__` method (which is used to create a class) and the `__new__` method of the class created by the metaclass (which is what creates an instance of the class).

Comment: Check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NAQEj-c2CI8) tech with tim youtube video. In which he explained about usage of __new__  in metaclass.

Comment: @GirishDattatrayHegde: good video. Thanks

Comment: @chepner: make_SA_Sorrogate should be make_SA_AddOn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make your metaclass inherit from `type` instead of `object`.

```
class SorrogateFactory(type):

    def __call__(self, classname, supers, classdict):
        print("In __call__")
        print("Making " + classname + " of" + " classname")
        Class = self.__new__(classname, supers, classdict)
        self.__init__(Class, classname, supers, classdict)
        return Class

    def __new__(self, classname, supers, classdict):
        print("In __new__")
        return type(classname, supers, classdict)

    def __init__(self):
        print("In __init__")
        pass


class SA_AddOn(object):
    pass
```

Also, just use the metaclass without the brackets, otherwise you will be instantiating it. That's why you are getting the error message about the 3 parameters.

```
class make_SA_Sorrogate(SA_AddOn, metaclass=SorrogateFactory):
    def dumb(slef):
        pass
```

Comment: The first argument to \_\_new__ is actually the class, not an instance of the class. Although what you have is correct, I would write `def __new__(cls, classname, supers, classdict):` for clarity.